# binomial, $P(x \ge k)$

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

What is $P(x \ge 10)$ given $n = 40$ and $p = 0.2$?

I calculated that the mean $= 8$ and sd $= 2.53$
Therefore $z = 0.791$, so $P = 1 - 0.7852 = 0.2148$.

How ever the answer shows as $0.2682$?

I see that there is a condition that $np$ and $np(1 - p)$ must be at least $10$ for the mean what is the alternative/ is this relevant?

Comment: What you're calculating is an *approximation*, and is not the exact value of $\Pr\left(X \geq k\right)$.

Comment: Yes, $np(1-p)$ is too small for reliability of the normal approximation. With continuity correction, probability that $Z\ge \frac{9.5-8}{2.53}$ we do somewhat better. The $0.2682$ looks like the actual probability, to $4$ decimal places, obtained by using the binomial. Nowadays there are plenty of pieces of software, and even some calculators, that will do the work.

Comment: @Clarinetist : You're identifying a small problem while neglecting a much bigger problem.  See my answer below. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\Pr(X\ge 10) = \Pr(X>9).
$$
The usual continuity correction approximated this by $\Pr(X\ge 9.5)$ and treating $X$ as normally distributed with the same expected value and the same standard deviation as the binomially distributed random variable.
\begin{align}
\Pr\left(\frac{X-8}{\sqrt{6.4}} \ge \frac{9.5-8}{\sqrt{6.4}}\right) \approx \Pr(Z\ge 0.5929271) = \Phi(0.5929271) \approx 0.276615.
\end{align}
My software is telling me that for the binomial distribution, rather than the normal approximation, one gets $\Pr(X\ge 10) \approx 0.2682229$.

Your biggest problem is not using the continuity correction.  But also, you should never do more rounding than is absolutely necessary until the very last step, unless you **know** what the effect of rounding at an early stage will be on the bottom line.  You did that twice.

Comment: where does the 6.4 come from? ---- never mind